# Find the heaviest ball by asking at most 8 questions

Tags: algorithm, interactive

Given 6 balls with **distinct** weights. The aim is to find the heaviest of these balls.

The problem proceeds in a question answer fashion, i.e. we have to ask questions and the problem setter provides us an answer.
Each question comprises of giving 5 indexes out of the six. The answer returned with be indices of 3<sup>rd</sup> heaviest and 2<sup>nd</sup> heaviest ball (in this order).
We can ask at most 8 such questions to find the heaviest ball.

*Example :*

Say the indices of balls are - `1,2,3,4,5,6`.

```
Q : 1 2 3 4 5     A : 3 4   (here 3 is the third most and 4 is the second most heaviest of the 5 balls)

Q : 1 2 3 4 6     A : 3 4

Q : 1 2 3 5 6     A : 3 5

Q : 1 2 4 5 6     A : 4 5

Q : 1 3 4 5 6     A : 4 5

Q : 2 3 4 5 6     A : 4 5
```

These 6 questions are sufficient to establish that ball with index 6 is the heaviest. (2 more questions can still be asked - we don't need to minimise number of questions. Also these queries may or may not order all the 6 numbers, our aim is to find the heaviest only).

---

I am looking for a general approach to solve this problem (preferably not involving case based analysis).

Comment: You can answer your own question by asking yourself how you arrived at the conclusion that "These 4 questions are sufficient to establish that ball with index 6 is the heaviest."

Comment: That was because I knew the order beforehand. Also I have arrived at a general solution for the problem but it involves too heavy case work. I want to know better approaches.

Comment: can you repeat indexes?

Comment: Yes we can repeat indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be programming.  And I suspect that you made up the puzzle because if it was off of a puzzle site, they should have figured out that it never needs more than 5 questions.

First of all, after the first 3 of your questions, the answer is already known to be 6.  How so?  The fact that the answer didn't change on question 2 says that either 5 and 6 are both > 4 > 3, or both < 3 < 4.  On question 3 it is revealed that 5 > 3 therefore 6 > 3.  And the fact that 5 shows up in #2 says that something is > 5, and the only possible answer is 6.  So we're done!

You just have to know what information you are collecting and apply it fully.

Now let's solve the problem in a more general way where we can figure it out even faster.

Our first round we know nothing, so we weight `1 2 3 4 5`.  This will produce an answer `x y`.  Exchange `x` with `6` and try again.  Here are the possibilities:

1. If we get `y z` with `z` not `6`, then our answer is `6` in 2 questions for the same reasoning that the answer was found before.
2. If we get `y 6` or `6 y` then it isn't `x`, `y` or `6`.  We exchange `x` for each of the other three until the second place answer changes.  The one where that happened is the heaviest, in a max of 5 questions.
3. If we get `z y` with `z` not `6` then `6` is lighter than `y` (else it would have pushed it down).  We now know that the answer isn't `x`, `y`, `z` or `6`.  So we just have to exchange `x` with the other two in turn applying the same reasoning as before to find the heaviest in a max of 4 questions.

Comment: I was about 3/4 with hints on using `topological ordering` -- you've covered the application here.  I think you've slipped into case analysis, but you illustrate the concepts well enough that OP can solve the problem either way.

Comment: Beautifully written

Answer (score 0):

I think It could be solved this way, with example:

input: 24, 7, 12, 1986, 6, 99

```
Q1: Give me second and third from set {24,7,12,1986,6}
A1: second 24, third 12
```

Now from this answer we know that 24 and 12 would never be the heaviest. So we can just remember that idx's {0,2} won't belong to our answer.
Lets now add idx 5 which we don't know anything about.

```
Q2: Give me second and third from set that includes our second from first answer {24,7,1986,6,99}
A2: second 99 third 24
```

Now we got second that is our new value so idx at value 99 can't be the heaviest. The same situation would happen if second from answer 1 would remain the same.
On the other hand if second would become third we already know that something heavier is at idx 5 that everything before, and this is the one.

In current state we have 3 indexes that are not heaviest for sure: (idx 0)24 (idx 2)12 and (idx 5)99.

Now lets ask for some set with idx we don't have any info, like idx 1.

```
Q3: Give me second and third from set {24,12,1986,6,99}
A3: second 99, third 24
```

This answer has not chnaged from what we got from answer 2 so we know its not under index 1. Rest of the algorithm is the same deduction step.

I.E:

We don't know anything about idx 3.

```
Q4: Give me second and third from set {24,7,12,6,99}
A4: second 24 and third 12
```

Here Second has changed as it was 99 previously that means index 3 made a difference, and its is the one.